# How to get location of all Apple devices on same Apple ID

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create an app that includes a functionality similar to Apple's Find my iPhone. I need to be able to get and display the location of all devices on the same Apple ID. Is there a way to achieve this either through some function or by getting the information using Apples Find My iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this

No, there isn’t. As so often happens, Apple reserves certain powers for itself alone. You can readily see, too, what a dreadful security hole this would be.

Comment: Of course the security cat is already out of the bag, so Apple's official position here is hypocritical. We _are_ being tracked in great detail by apps without being told so, as this week's New York Times so ably demonstrated. However, that's irrelevant to the question as posed.

Comment: Probably not the place to discuss this, but I don't know if Apple is being hypocritical; I trust that Apple isn't monetising the location I share for the purposes of find my iPhone, and at least you can easily limit location use on iOS to "when in use", which I understand isn't the case on Android.  The difficulty is that we as users needs to trade off the benefit we get from letting apps use our location with the risks of how they might use that location.  I don't know what Apple can do apart from booting the most egregious apps when they find them.